# How to remove "copy" folder in linux terminal

Tags: linux, shell

```
rm -r demo (copy);
```

The error is:

> No such file or directory

But the directory is there. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape yor path string:

`rm -r demo\ \(copy\)`

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrapper the file path with quote:

```
rm -r "demo (copy)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -r test\ \(copy\)
```

> Special characters should prefixed with `\` (backslash).